# the function should return a single object which has key as the parameter someKey and value as someValue

Tags: typescript

the function should return a 
single object
 which has key as the parameter 
someKey and value as someValue

```
let convertToKeyValuePair = (someKey,someValue)=>{

    return { someKey : someValue}

    // this function should return a single object which has      
    //key as the value of someKey and value as someValue
};

console.log(convertToKeyValuePair("someKey","someValue"))

let convertToKeyValuePair = (someKey,someValue)=>{

   // this function should return a single object which has      
   //key as the value of someKey and value as someValue

};



module.exports = {convertToKeyValuePair:convertToKeyValuePair};
```

Comment: What is your question....?

Comment: Is the "typescript" tag relevant?  Do you want a strongly typed version of `convertToKeyValuePair()` [like this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/DYUwLgBAxg9gdgNxAJzAFRgaRATwGoCGwAriAAoECWyEAvBADyYQgAeYIcAJgM4QDWuGADMIBODgA0EPAD4AFACgIEHjAC2IbDgBcETJOWqNIQiRB68igJR1ZEeQG8IAbTWbtAXT3vTRUhAAvmJ8zi5kEJRw+t4yQdYA3IqKsHA8kDAARgBWdNDwSKgY2makFNTyAES+2pXS1SalIJWJigD0bflpGTl6zsYeuD5gyFEA5gkqgcmp6RBZ2QAylBzIRHmphehYuE3lyFU1uHUQDZpNlSFd6a0d1z1LKyhEfSpHuqe+F5NBikA)?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to use a [computed property name](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer)? Add square brackets around the variable:

```
let convertToKeyValuePair = (someKey,someValue)=>{

    return { [someKey] : someValue}

    // this function should return a single object which has      
    //key as the value of someKey and value as someValue
};
```